# R: How to customize an axis on an image of sparse matrix generated with image{Matrix}

Tags: image, r, sparse-matrix

I want to modify the name on the x and y axis of the image of a sparse matrix
generated by the function Matrix::image.
When I run the code below

```
library(Matrix)
image(CAex, axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2,at = 1:80, labels = 1:80, las = 1,add = TRUE)
```

I get the error message below.

```
Error in axis(side = 2, at = 1:80, labels = 1:80, las = 1, add = TRUE) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `Matrix::image` uses the `levelplot` function of the `lattice` package to draw the plot, not the `image` function of the standard `graphics` package. Axis properties are specified in a different way for lattice plots, see the `scales` argument of `?xyplot`.

The following would be the lattice equivalent of your `axis` command above:

```
image(CAex, scales=list(y=list(at=1:80)))
```

[image: Matrix::image]

Btw, you don't need `add=TRUE` for axis, that's how it always behaves.